Showing a real part of a complex valued matrix is invertible using some properties
I would love to get some hints on one part of my HW assignment. I was able to derive the following properties in the preceding parts:

Given $R,S \in M_{n\times n} (\mathbb{R})$, $R+iS$ is invertible.
$\mathrm{im}_\mathbb{C}(R) = \mathrm{im}_\mathbb{C}(S)$.
$\mathrm{im}(A+B) \subset \mathrm{span}(\mathrm{im}(A) \cup \mathrm{im}(B))$.
$\ker(R) \cap \ker(S) = \{0\}$.

Using these four results, I want to show that $R$ is invertible. I began some scratch work to show that $\ker(R) = \{0\}$.
Suppose $x \neq 0 \in \ker(R) \implies Rx=0$. By 4., $x \notin \ker(S)$. Therefore, denote $ b \neq 0$ such that $Sx = b$. Then it follows that $b \in \mathrm{im}(S) = \mathrm{im}(R)$.
After this, I thought I might be able to somehow show that $x$ is in the kernel of $R+iS$, which is a contradiction because $R+iS$ is invertible... Any hint/nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!
